# Java: Force string name to be accepted as a class?

Tags: java, string, variables, object, printing

I want to print out a statement like so:

```
Object SomeObject = new Object("object's name");
System.out.println(SomeObject.name);
```

except rather than specifying the name of the Object in the print statement, specify a String which would have earlier been declared as the name of an existing object.

Example:

```
Object SomeObject = new Object("object's name");
String object_string = "SomeObject";
System.out.println("object_string.name");
```

I know that the first example would print out "object's name". I want the second one to do the same, but using the string. Note that the value of the string is the same as the object name. Obviously the second example won't work, because object_string is a string, not an object.

So my question is, can I force the print statement to accept "object_string" as the name of an Object?

```
System.out.println("(Object)object_string.name");
```

Something like that perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Do you know about Class.forName()?

Comment: What exactly is Class.forName()?

Comment: It allows you to retrieve a class based on a string name. I can't tell if it would help you or not.

Comment: Could you provide a quick example where you would use Class.forName()? I might be able to tell if it would help me then or not.

Comment: Class<?> stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");

Comment: It can be used to initialize a class, our in conjunction with newInstance, instantiate it. See the [Class docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this? What is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: @DaveNewton pretty sure the OP is looking for interpolation, not reflection.

Comment: @Dan Ah, that could be, hard to say. But with string int. you'd still need "${object_string.name}", wouldn't you?

Comment: @DaveNewton well, in any of the Java-based implementations I've used, yes. But it looks like the OP isn't aware of those. And one could conceive of a system that didn't require that and dealt with the amiguity some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called String Interpolation (at least that's what it's called in Perl, which is the example I'm most familiar with) and Java doesn't have it, sorry. However, there are some tools built on top of Java that offer similar functionality in more specialized use cases. You might, for example, be interested in [JSP EL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html), [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/), or [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

Note, however, that all of these require some scaffolding to set up, and in particular, the objects you reference in these dynamic contexts must be first placed into some kind of map or other holder. There's no way to reference them directly from a local variable.

On the other hand, some other languages like Groovy offer this feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go from String to a named variable name, object_string variable no longer exists when compiled to byte code and there is no way for the compiler to know that "object_string" references the variable object_string. That is of course unless you have a map of string to variables you control.

You're better off using reflection to look for a property 'name' and printing that.

```
public void printProperty(Class<?> cl, String propertyName) {
   //Use reflection here to look up the propertyName on class cl and print
}

printProperty(Object.class, 'name');
```